# About executing shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, path, executable

Suppose I have a shell script file `foo.sh`.

I can do `chmod + x foo.sh` 
and change it into an executable file.

In Kernighan-Pike: Unix Programming Environment (UP) they show that after this typing `foo` should execute the script. Instead in my Ubuntu system I need to type `sh foo` or `./foo`. 
I am guessing this is due to some feature of the shell that wasn't present earlier (when UP was written). I will appreciate if some can enlighten me why this difference exists and why is it important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The name of the executable is important.  If your file is named `foo.sh`, then executing `foo` will not work unless there is some other executable named `foo`.  Unlike Windows, Unix does not do *implicit* file extensions.
2. If the following works:

   ```
   ./foo.sh
   ```

   But this doesn't:

   ```
   foo.sh
   ```

   That means that the file is in your current directory and your current directory is not in your PATH.  For your protection, if you don't explicitly provide the path to a command, the shell will only look for the command among files that are in your PATH.
3. Spaces are important.  The following may work:

   ```
   ./foo.sh
   ```

   But, this (taken from the first version of this question) certainly will not work:

   ```
   ./ foo.sh
   ```

   With a space between `./` and `foo.sh`, the shell will think that you want to execute the current directory with `foo.sh` as an argument.  This will generate an error message.

Comment: Note that back when Kernighan&Pike was written, it was common to have the current directory (".") in the PATH (meaning that `foo.sh` would work without the `./`). This was a found to be a security problem (someone could leave e.g. a malicious script named "ls" in their directory, then trick other people into running it), so it's no longer common (or recommended) practice.

Comment: @Gordon; the problem with the `.` in `PATH` was specifically considered bad if you have the `.` at the beginning of the `PATH` sequence. If you have the `.` at the end of `PATH` the system commands (like your `ls` sample) will always be found (and executed) before the executables in `.` (the current directory).